# VIM: combine two searches

Tags: search, vim

Often I do a search for something (using hotkeys, menu command or commandline) and after that I want to keep the first search and add another search..

p.e.
- First I search doubles spaces in my text.
- Then I want to keep the matches and add the search all end of line spaces

Is there a way to combine 2 searches?

1) search 1
2) press F9 or other key: ADD
3) search 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
exe '/\('.histget('/',-1).'\)\|\('.newSearch.'\)'
```

where newSearch is your new search string.  A nice way of doing it is just do the searches separately to make sure you get what you want and then combine them with:

```
exe '/\('.histget('/',-1).'\)\|\('.histget('/',-2).'\)'
```

You can do this repeatedly to build quite long search strings, since it builds a new search string in the history.

This just or's the searches together, which isn't quite the same as what you asked, (since it doesn't keep the same matches).  It just concatenates the search criteria--but I suspect it's what you meant.

Comment: thanks... but not easy to make this work as I want because I continue find strange things in search history window.

Comment: Everytime this code is added in my search history windows: `\V\^    \zs\(\.\{-}\)\$` Is that the "/" and <UP>arrow when VIM searches in the search history window?

Comment: @Remonn: I think you must have an autocommand that does a search (or less likely) a substitute.  Interpreting the regular expression, it looks like it matches lines that start with a space.  Does that ring a bell?

Answer (score 2):

You could just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>\</kbd> then <kbd>Up-Arrow</kbd> to scroll back through your searches and edit your previous search to include the extra term.  So the first <kbd>Up-Arrow</kbd> will show your last search.

**Example**

You wanted to search for the text `_pipe(` so you typed:
<kbd>Esc</kbd> `/_pipe(`

You now want to add to that search and decide that as well as `_pipe(` it would be useful to only include the ones with the argument `option` so you type:
<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Up-Arrow</kbd>

and then edit your previous search to read `/_pipe(.*option.*)`

This now uses the new search which is updated from the previous search.

Comment: To work on previous search, you can also use `q/` to edit previously typed search. In the newly open window, you can use all usual Vim commands (yank, paste, change, etc).

Answer (score 2):

In Normal mode, you can use the last search register (`"/`)to recall your last search pattern:

```
/<C-r>/\|\(\[ ]\+$\)
```

Breaking it down:

- `<C-r>` is <kbd>CTRL + r</kbd>, it will bring up a `"` so you can choose a register,
- <kbd>/</kbd> to choose the search register,
- `\|` to add another pattern in your search (`OR`),
- `\(\[ ]\+$\)` search for and group trailing spaces.

Comment: thak you. I knew this one. However it doesn't work for search history -2

Comment: If you add search patterns incrementally, then it works by definition. If you wanted to recall the second last search pattern, then of course it doesn't work.